# Factorization of $x^6 - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I started by intuition since I'm familiar with the formula $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$. So in our case $$x^6 - 1 = ({x^3} - 1)({x^3}+1)$$

How should I proceed? I assume there's some sort of algorithm to keep the process till you reach a form of irreducible linear polynomials.

Comment: You might note that $x=\pm1$ are solutions of $x^6-1=0$ so you should be able to factor out $x-1$ and $x+1$

Comment: Oh and there's a theorm that if $f(\alpha) = 0$ then $(x-\alpha)|f(x)$. Right?

Comment: You would have to explain what you meant by  $(x-\alpha)|f(x)$ but for polynomials with real or complex coefficients the answer is essentially yes. If $f(x)=g(x)(x-\alpha)+k$ for some constant $k$ and $f(\alpha)=0$, then $k=0$ so  $(x-\alpha)|f(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

${x^3} - 1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

${x^3} + 1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

The last quadratic term is already irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$.

If you mean irreducible in $\mathbb{C}$, you may split it into product of factor $(x-e^{inw})$, where $n=0\cdots 5$,$w=\frac{\pi}{3}$ .

Comment: How can one think of that other then intuition?

Comment: @AlonAlon: In these cases, intuition and experience is far superior to trying to do things algorithmically.

Comment: @AlonAlon $x^3-1$ has 1 as a root, so must be divisible by $(x-1)$, and $x^3 + 1$ has -1 as a root, so must be divisble by $x - (-1) = x+1$. The long division of polynomials does the rest.

Comment: @AlonAlon In special cases such that $a^n-b^n$, we can also use some useful formula to help us.

Answer (score 3):

In general, we have:

$$x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots+ 1).$$

It is a particular instance of: $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}).$$

---

Think of the geometric progression $(a_1, \ldots, a_n,\ldots)$, with common ratio $q$. Then: $$a_1+\ldots +a_n = a_1 \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}.$$

This gives: $$1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1} = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.$$

Comment: @AlonAlon, please check my edit.

Comment: Thank you Ivo for those insights!

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$$

$$x^3 + 1 = (x+1)(x^2-x + 1)$$

Comment: How can one think of that other then intuition?

Comment: Note that $x = \pm 1$ is a root, then use polynomial long division (dividing by $x \mp 1$) to find the quadratic. In no time at all, you'll realize a pattern $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 2):

The linear factors always include complex numbers as soon as $n>2$.  They always pair up into real quadratic factors $(x^2-2x\cos(2k\pi/n)+1)$

Comment: Um, what? for example, $x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$ factors completely into linear factors in the reals, even though it has degree $>2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for $x^n-1$

Answer (score 2):

By the Rational Root Theorem, the only possible rational roots of $x^3 - 1$ are $\pm 1$. Substituting gives that $x = 1$ is a root, so that $x - 1$ is a factor of $x^3 - 1$. Then polynomial division gives
$$x^3 - 1 = (x - 1) (x^2 + x + 1).$$
Similarly,
$$x^3 + 1 = (x + 1) (x^2 - x + 1).$$
The discriminant of $x^2 \pm x + 1$ is $-3 < 0$, so the quadratic factors do not factor over $\mathbb{R}$, so this furnishes the complete factorization of $x^6 - 1$ into polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

If you want a factorization over $\mathbb{C}$ instead, you can use that $$x^m - 1 = \prod_{i = 1}^m (x - \zeta_i),$$ where $\zeta_i$ varies over the $m$th roots of unity.